# Snowflake fill cursor using dynamic SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to fill a cursor using a dynamic SQL statement?

Something like this:

```
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2';
```

And then iterate through the values (1,2)

I've tried to do so using the Snowflake UI but I am getting an error:

```
syntax error line 1 at position 31 unexpected 'IMMEDIATE'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably looking for something like this :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE
  CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT 1 as id UNION SELECT 2;
BEGIN
  OPEN CUR;
  RETURN TABLE(RESULTSET_FROM_CURSOR(CUR));
END;
$$
;
```

Result :

```
ID
1
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But that is not exactly what I am looking for, meaning, the SELECT has to be a dynamic string. I used "select 1 union select 2" as a simplified example. But the real problem I am trying to solve is a more complex query with different WHERE clauses calculated based on other calculations